# Compute the mean and std over a column with awk

Tags: awk, mean, standard-deviation

I have this file:

```
Took:  15.473214149475098  seconds
Took:  12.94953465461731  seconds
Took:  2.235722780227661  seconds
Took:  40.53083419799805  seconds
Took:  21.840606212615967  seconds
Took:  35.777870893478394  seconds
Took:  13.153780221939087  seconds
Took:  2.966165781021118  seconds
Took:  35.54965615272522  seconds
```

I would like to compute the mean and std of the times directly in the terminal. Can `awk` help ? I am not very familiar with it. I tried splitting the file to get the column with the numerical values only this way :
`cat <filename> | awk -F "Took:" {print$2}` but it just returned the whole content of the file.

Comment: What's the expected output? ;D

Comment: and provide the algorithm you want to use to calculate the values you want output.

Answer (score 4):

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) on Standard deviation has an interesting section, [*"Rapid calculation methods"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods). Of particular interest is the [Welford's algorithm](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1266577?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), that is simple and numerically stable:

> ```
> A_0, Q_0 = 0, 0
> for k in (1, ...):
>     j = k-1
>     A_k = A_j + (X_k-A_j)/k
>     Q_k = Q_j + (X_k-A_j)*(X_k-A_k)
> ```

where, at every step, `A_k` is equal to the running mean and `Q_k` is related to the population variance σ² by the relation `Q_k = σ²*k`.

With this theoretical background, we can write

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{a=0;q=0}{x=$2;b=a+(x-a)/NR;q+=(x-a)*(x-b);a=b}END{print a,sqrt(q/NR)}' file
```

Comment: `BEGIN{a=0;q=0}` is not strictly necessary because in Awk numerical variables are automagically initialized to 0 but I've liked to mimic as close as possible the published algorithm. In other words, the one-liner `awk '{x=$2;b=a+(x-a)/NR;q+=(x-a)*(x-b);a=b}END{print a,sqrt(q/NR)}'` is equivalent to the one in the answer.

Comment: last link is broken.

Comment: @karakfa changed the link, thanks a lot for the heads up

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following to get mean of 2nd column.

```
awk '{sum+=$2;if($2){count++}} END{print sum/count}'  Input_file
```

***EDIT:***

```
awk '{if($2!=""){count++;sum+=$2};y+=$2^2} END{sq=sqrt(y/NR-(sum/NR)^2);sq=sq?sq:0;print "Mean = "sum/count ORS "S.D = ",sq}'  Input_file
```

Comment: is it possible to print both mean and std with the same command line ?

Comment: `if($2)` You don't want zeros messing with your results? ;D

Comment: Try with: `echo -e 1\\n0\\n2 | awk ...`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I downvoted because your script produces wrong results if there is a zero in column 2.

Comment: Since you have `if($2)` it will not process zero values and the average of 0,1,2  is 1.5, not 1.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I think we should, that's how you produce reliable code.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The average of 0,1,2 is 1, your script gives 1.5 because it does not process zeroes due to `if($2)`, replace it with `if($2!="")`or something.

Comment: It outputs one, so I'll give you one. ;D

Answer (score 3):

another quick way,

```
$ awk '{s+=$2; ss+=$2^2} END{print m=s/NR, sqrt(ss/NR-m^2)}' file

20.053 13.4924
```

Comment: `print m=1, m*2` — never seen that, it's a nice trick, isn't it?

Comment: assignments carry the value, that's why you can write `a=b=1` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ numbers[NR] = $2; sum += $2 }
END {
    mean = sum / length(numbers)
    # calculate std deviation
    for (i in numbers) {
        dif = numbers[i] - mean
        std += dif ^ 2
    }
    std = sqrt(std / length(numbers))

    print "Mean: " mean
    print "Standart Deviation: " std
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Mean: 20.053
Standart Deviation: 13.4924
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> cat dada.txt 
Took:  15.473214149475098  seconds
Took:  12.94953465461731  seconds
Took:  2.235722780227661  seconds
Took:  40.53083419799805  seconds
Took:  21.840606212615967  seconds
Took:  35.777870893478394  seconds
Took:  13.153780221939087  seconds
Took:  2.966165781021118  seconds
Took:  35.54965615272522  seconds
> perl -lane '$s+=$F[1];push(@a,$F[1]); END { $m=$s/@a; $sd+=($_-$m)**2 for(@a);$sd=sqrt($sd/@a); print "Mean:$m\nStandard Deviation:$sd"} ' dada.txt
Mean:20.0530427826775
Standard Deviation:13.4923983082523
>
```